# What does Baym mean here in his Lecture on Identical Particles?

Tags: wavefunction, identical-particles, spin-statistics

I'm reading *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics* by Gordon Baym (1969). In his discussion of 3-identical fermions Baym writes: "One way to make $\Psi(1,2,3)$ [the total wave-function] antisymmetric is to take a symmetric $\chi\left(s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}\right)$ times an antisymmetric $\psi\left(\mathbf{r}_{1}, \mathbf{r}_{2}, \mathbf{r}_{3}\right) .$ The other way around won't work, since it isn't possible to construct a completely antisymmetric spin wave function $\chi\left(\mathrm{s}_{1}, \mathrm{s}_{2}, \mathrm{s}_{3}\right)$ from just the two choices, up or down, for each spin. There is another possibility though. Suppose that we take a $\chi\left(\mathrm{s}_{1}, \mathrm{s}_{2}, \mathrm{s}_{3}\right)$ that is antisymmetric in $\mathrm{s}_{2}$ and $\mathrm{s}_{3},$ for example,"
$$
\chi(s_1,s_2,s_3)=\chi_{\uparrow}\left(\mathrm{s}_{1}\right)\left[\chi_{\uparrow}\left(\mathrm{s}_{2}\right) \chi_{\downarrow}\left(\mathrm{s}_{3}\right)-\chi_{\downarrow}\left(\mathrm{s}_{2}\right) \chi_{\uparrow}\left(\mathrm{s}_{3}\right)\right]
$$
Baym goes on to construct the totally anti-symmetric wave-function:
$$
\Psi(1,2,3)=\chi\left(\mathrm{s}_{1}, \mathrm{s}_{2}, \mathrm{s}_{3}\right) \psi\left(\mathrm{r}_{1}, \mathrm{r}_{2}, \mathrm{r}_{3}\right)+\chi\left(\mathrm{s}_{2}, \mathrm{s}_{3}, \mathrm{s}_{1}\right) \psi\left(\mathrm{r}_{2}, \mathrm{r}_{3}, \mathrm{r}_{1}\right) 
+ \chi\left(\mathrm{s}_{3}, \mathrm{s}_{1}, \mathrm{s}_{2}\right) \psi\left(\mathrm{r}_{3}, \mathrm{r}_{1}, \mathrm{r}_{2}\right)
$$
My question is what exactly Baym means when he says "it isn't possible to construct a completely antisymmetric spin wave function $χ(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ from just the two choices, up or down, for each spin.", and how his latter construction is different from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible completely antisymmetric wave function for three spins $1/2$ is identical zero. From three spin variables $s_1, s_2, s_3$, each being equal $1/2$ or $-1/2$, at least two have same value. The antisymmetry of wave function leads to its zero value in this case.

Comment: Does this imply Bayms construction is the zero vector?

Comment: @Craig. This implies there is no completely antisymmetric function of the form $\chi(s_1,s_2,s_3)\psi(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ where $\chi$ is antisymmetric and $\psi$ is symmetric.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! Do you know how one would translate this spin cooridnate description to the typical Bra-Ket notation? Thanks

Comment: As I understand, the wave function is a particular representation of a ket-vector
$\Psi(1,2,3) = \langle 1,2,3|\Psi\rangle$.